# Reading text file into structured 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a structured 2D numpy array of shape : [2,2]

**filled  example [2,2] array:**

***Main_Clt_data_array :***

```
[ [ ((10, 10), 20, 300.) ((20, 20), 20, 300.) ]
  [((30, 30), 30, 300.) ((40, 40), 40, 300.)] ]
```

---

**It is of the following datatype**

```
Cord_dtype = np.dtype([('X', np.float64), ('Y', np.float64)])
Clt_data_dtype=np.dtype([('Coord', Cord_dtype),('Angle', np.float64), ('Length', np.float64)])
```

---

Using `np.savetxt` i was able to save the array into a txt file maintaing same shape and order.

**'Trial.txt' :**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DpCz.png)

---

***but when i try to read into python using genfromtxt,It does not work.:***
example:

```
read_array = np.genfromtxt('Trial.txt',dtype=Clt_data_dtype)
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
('READ_ARRAY_shape :', (2L,))

('READ_ARRAY :', array([((nan, nan), nan, nan), ((nan, nan), nan, nan)], 'V32'))
```

---

***Hope some one could guide me and Thanks in advance for any input***

*also note i cannot use pandas as i am running it only numpy compatable program*

Comment: `trial.txt` is small enough that you could have copy-n-pasted it to the question.  We like that much better than an image.  What `savetxt` command did you use?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [17]: Cord_dtype = np.dtype([('X', np.float64), ('Y', np.float64)])
    ...: Clt_data_dtype=np.dtype([('Coord', Cord_dtype),('Angle', np.float64), ('Length', np.float64)])
```

Creating your array:

```
In [18]: arr = np.array([ [ ((10, 10), 20, 300.), ((20, 20), 20, 300.) ],
    ...:   [((30, 30), 30, 300.), ((40, 40), 40, 300.)] ], dtype=Clt_data_dtype)
    ...: 
    ...: 
In [19]: arr
Out[19]: 
array([[((10., 10.), 20., 300.), ((20., 20.), 20., 300.)],
       [((30., 30.), 30., 300.), ((40., 40.), 40., 300.)]],
      dtype=[('Coord', [('X', '<f8'), ('Y', '<f8')]), ('Angle', '<f8'), ('Length', '<f8')])
In [20]: arr.shape
Out[20]: (2, 2)
```

`genfromtxt` can recreate it from a `csv` style file like:

```
In [21]: txt = """10 10 20 300.
    ...: 20 20 20 300.
    ...: 30 30 30 300.
    ...: 40 40 40 300.
    ...: """
     
In [22]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=Clt_data_dtype)
Out[22]: 
array([((10., 10.), 20., 300.), ((20., 20.), 20., 300.),
       ((30., 30.), 30., 300.), ((40., 40.), 40., 300.)],
      dtype=[('Coord', [('X', '<f8'), ('Y', '<f8')]), ('Angle', '<f8'), ('Length', '<f8')])
```

In true `csv` fashion this just contains rows and columns of numbers.  It does not have the delimiters and `()` that your `img` shows.  It may be possible to parse your image and create the file, but a `csv` reader can't handle.